# How do I filter the words out of this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?period1=1570838400&period2=1602460800&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true'

df=pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]
df = df[:-1]
print(df)
```

out:

```
           Date      Dividends     Unnamed: 2     Unnamed: 3     Unnamed: 4     Unnamed: 5     Unnamed: 6
0  Aug 19, 2020  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend
1  May 20, 2020  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend
2  Feb 19, 2020  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend
3  Nov 20, 2019  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend  0.51 Dividend
```

I need the .51 as a float rather than a string. How can I remove the ' Dividend' from each cell? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.replace('Dividend',"",regex=True)
```